# is it possible for a query to return the wildcard that matches a given string?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following table  in postgres:

```
Table "public.items"
    
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id          | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('items_id_seq'::regclass)
 wildcard    | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
```

The `wildcard` column value contains wildcards of the form:`stackoverflow*`.

This should match any word that begins with `'stackoverflow'`.

How can I locate the record that contains the a matching wild card?

For example, given `'stackoverflow.com'` I would like to return all wildcards matching it.
something like

Comment: When you say "of the form:'stackoverflow*'", what form is that?  For LIKE, the wildcard is '%' not '\*'.  For regular expressions, it is '.\*'  So what pattern language are you implying with your example?

Comment: I see, yup. I can change the format as long as It possible to query. I want to do the reverse like query.
`select from table where wildcard matches string`
I am thinking it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your wildcards with `%` instead of `*` and use `like`:

```
select *
from items
where 'stackoverflow.com' like wildcard
```

Or if you must use `*`, same but replace `*` with `%`:

```
select *
from items
where 'stackoverflow.com' like replace(wildcard, `*`, `%`)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in reverse match operator, but you can just swap the position of the arguments to get the reversed match:

```
select * from items where 'stackoverflow.com' LIKE items.wildcard;
```

Now, you can't get use of an index this way around, but that is only a barrier to performance, it won't stop you from running the query and getting an answer.